# Discord username format check

Tags: regex

How can I check if the username is in the right format?

For example in this format: Test#1234

And not check more than 4 numbers after #.

How can I do that?

Comment: It is not very clear what is the Format of the username, and what it is what you want. Do you want to ignore everything after 4 numbers? How about usernames like "#1234", "Test#1234566Test", "Test#", "Test#123", etc.

Comment: Yeah after 4 digits will be ignored.

The Discord username format is usually so Test#1234 so before # can be numbers and letter and different special characters and after # only 4 numbers. It needs to check too if there is # between them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do you want a regex like this one?

```
/^((.+?)#\d{4})/
```

This will match your format and ignore what's following the 4 digits.
Change the dot by the characters you want to match.

Comment: Maybe we should use `/^((.{2,32})#\d{4})/` instead since it checks for username length?

Comment: Or maybe `/^((?!(discordtag|everyone|here)#)((?!@|#|:|```).{2,32})#\d{4})/` because usernames also has some other rules they must follow: https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/user#usernames-and-nicknames

Answer (score 1):

This is what I came up with

```
(?!(discordtag|here|everyone)).[^\@\#\:]{2,32}#[\d]{4}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have not provided a language I will answer this in JavaScript regex. If I am understanding your problem correctly you're looking to match a string of letters and numbers followed by a hashtag and 4 numbers. We can do that with a very concise expression. `\w+` will match one or more letters and numbers and `#\d{4}` will match a hashtag followed by exactly 4 numbers. Your complete expression will be `/\w+#\d{4}/i`. I have added the `i` to the end to ignore case so that the text will match whether it is in caps or not.

```js
const str = 'hello my username is Text#1234.';

console.log(str.match(/\w+#\d{4}/i));
```

Answer (score 0):

````
/^(?!(here|everyone))^(?!.*(discord|```)).[^\@\#\:]{2,32}#\d{4}$/s
````

[Documentation](https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/user#usernames-and-nicknames)

Answer (score 0):

As per the [documentation](https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/user#usernames-and-nicknames) I am able to handle most of the cases using the below code:

```
var discordVal = $('#discordInput').val();
var allow_ascii_match = /(?=\S+)#[\d]{4}$/;
var discord_word_match = /(discordtag|everyone|here|discord)/i;
var except_chars_match = /[@:,`]/;
if (discordVal != '' && 
 (!allow_ascii_match.test(discordVal) || 
 discord_word_match.test(discordVal) || 
 except_chars_match.test(discordVal) || 
 discordVal.match(/#/gi).length > 1) ) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
```

Following test cases for reference purpose:

- Crème@Brûleé#1234 -invalid
- ᗅᗺᗷ#ᗅ#2344   -invalid
- user test#1234  -Valid
- discord test#1234   -invalid
- discord#1234   -invalid
- DISCORD #1234   -invalid
- test@example#1234   -invalid
- here#1234     -invalid
- HErE       -invalid
- DisCoRD test#1212   -invalid
- testdiscordexample#1234   -invalid
- #user#est#1234   -invalid
- 12324324#1234   -Valid